# Features in a classifier

Tags: python, nltk, text-classification

I am testing different classifiers (SVM, Logistic Regression, Random Forest, Naive Bayes, Gradient Boosting).

My dataset is similar to this:

```
Text                 User         Date          Label
some text here     LucaDiMauro   2020/02/12        0
learning ML!!!     Mika          2018/12/03        1
Attention please!  user2         2012/02/04        1
```

and so on.

`1` identifies normal content; `0` identifies potential spam content.

I identified the most important features that can capture credibility in subject: presence of numbers in the username, number of words, characters, special characters, use of pronouns, use of number at the beginning of the sentence. I would like to know how to check performance of classifiers (need one, not all) with these selected features.

Some of my features are as follows:

```
df['Punctuation']=df['Text'].str.findall('[?!<>']+')
Count = df['Text'].str.split().str.len()
df['comma_count'] = df.Text.str.count(',')
df.Text.astype(str).sum(axis=1).str.len()
df['User'] = pd.np.where(Text.str.contains("0"),"None",
```

I would like just to see how to consider also these features in a model to predict some other spam/not spam email.
It is not clear how to include these features in my classifier. I have always considered Text as variable for cleaning, pre-processing... and I have never taken into consideration other features: only Label (y) and Text as X.

For instance, I used this classifier:

```
# Import train_test_split function
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn import metrics

# Split dataset into training set and test set

y=df['Label']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.30, stratify=y)

# all parameters not specified are set to their defaults
logisticRegr = LogisticRegression()
logisticRegr.fit(X_train, y_train)

logisticRegr.predict(X_test[0].reshape(1,-1))

logisticRegr.predict(X_test[0:10])

predictions = logisticRegr.predict(X_test)

score = logisticRegr.score(X_test, y_test)
print(score)

cm = metrics.confusion_matrix(y_test, predictions)
print(cm)
```

I would like to know if in this code I am considering the other features or only Text.
If you could give me an example of integration of some features in a classifier would be extremely useful.

Comment: Did you try out any options ? If so, what did you try. Can you share that with us so we can see how we can help you to address the issue.

Comment: Ooooo, this looks like a case for text classification. Ok... here we go. 1) Read up about feature engineering pertaining to text classification. You mention you used counts of words, etc. However raw counts may not be indicative of spam/no-spam. Instead, use TF-IDF. 2) The vocab in your corpus of emails can blow up quickly. There is also the case where your vocab list is unknown. Use the [hashing trick](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.HashingVectorizer.html) as it will solve issues where new words can appear in test sets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the pre-processing you've done.

If you are unsure if other features are included, just try printing the head of X and see if you have other features included.

Considering the pre-processing you've done, your code most likely considers the other features unless you've deliberately decided to consider only 'Text' for X.

*On a side note*, if you've extracted useful information from the Text attribute and have them as separate attributes, you may not really need 'Text' anymore.

Couldn't add a comment as I am new here. Could you please include the head of X in the question?

**Edit:**
You can try this..

```
# Extract features from Text and User as per your observations..
df['Punctuation']= df['Text'].str.contains("[?!<>']+")
Count = df['Text'].str.split().str.len()
df['comma_count'] = df.Text.str.count(',')
df['UserHasDigit'] = df['User'].apply(lambda x: 1 if(any(char.isdigit() for char in x)) == True else 0)

# Add more if you find any useful features

# Split the dependent (Target/Label) column from independent (features) columns
y = df['Label']
X = df.drop(columns=['Text', 'User', 'Label', 'Date']) # Drop attributes from which you extracted features and the ones that add no value

# print the head of X and y to see if it is correct
print("X")
print(X.head())
print("------")
print("y")
print(y.head())

# Apply any encoding if needed (Label-encoding / one-hot encoding)
# Now, apply test train split
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.30, stratify=y)

# carry on with the modeling as usual..

# ----- copied from your code ------
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn import metrics
.
.
.
.
```

In this code, it is considering all the features (punctuation, comma_count, UserHasDigit.. more if you added more features) and not 'Text' as it has been dropped.